# How does the effect size inform the design (or analysis) of an NHST?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, effect-size, neyman-pearson-lemma

Consider [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/103059/27838) on how to design an NHST. I don't quite understand what **exact process** one is supposed to follow to determine the  **minimum sample size** once we have:

- A **null hypothesis** that is **falsifiable**. The choice of this null hypothesis will inform the assumed distribution of the data *under the null*.
- A **minimum** *effect* size that we want to be able to observe.
- A **maximum** *false positive rate*, i.e. the significant level $\alpha$ against which we'll compare a computed $p$ value.
- The **maximum** *false negative rate* =  1-$\beta$, i.e. where $\beta$ is called the power or sensitivity of the experiment.

If simpler, let's assume a 1D Normal distribution for the Null.

My recollection is that one is supposed to use the **CDF** of the Null somehow for the test, but how? E.g. how does the chosen value for the minimum effect size inform the sample size?

Comment: You also need information about the distribution under the alternate hypothesis.

Comment: Interesting @whuber I thought the idea is to test if we can _reject_ the Null given the decision parameters that I stated above, and without necessarily stating what's a better fitting hypothesis. Or are you saying that the notion of the **effect size** specifically only makes sense when comparing **two** hypotheses (in fact two distributions), and **not** just trying to see if we could reject the hypothesis that a particular sample comes from a (single) assumed distribution?

Comment: You can't even define an effect size without having two hypotheses to compare.